# how do I loop backward for 4 values and do it for next values in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of values like this

```
list1 =[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,45.2,0.0,0.0,12.3,32.3,62.6,19.01,0.0,65.1,1.5,0.0,0.0,41.6,0.0,27.4,139.21,0.0,27.75,696.94,66.97,0.0]
```

My list1 is a column from a dataframe and I converted it into list by doing .tolist()

```
list2 = [0.27, 0.29, 0.24, 0.18]
```

I would like to multiply

```
[0.0*0.27 + 0.0*0.29 + 0.0*0.24 + 0.0*0.18] = 0
[0.0*0.27 + 0.0*0.29 + 0.0*0.24 + 0.0*0.18] = 0
[45.2*0.27 + 0.0*0.29 + 0.0*0.24 + 0.0*0.18] = 12.20
[0.0*0.27 + 45.2*0.29 + 0.0*0.24 + 0.0*0.18] = 13.108
[0.0*0.27 + 0.0*0.29 + 45.2*0.24 + 0.0*0.18] = 10.848
[12.3*0.27 + 0.0*0.29 + 0.0*0.24 + 45.2*0.18] = 8.136
```

...
and so on to other values also
Basically, it is going in a reverse way on list1 values.

So I think we can do list indexing like:

```
for i in list1[4:0:-1]
   print(i)
```

But this happens only to the values which I gave, how do I do that to all the values.
If nan will be an issue we can just do .fillna(0)

Comment: `list1 =[nan,nan,nan,nan,0.0,0.0,45.2,0.0,0.0,12.3,32.3,62.6,19.01,0.0,65.1,1.5,0.0,0.0,41.6,0.0,27.4,139.21,0.0,27.75,696.94,66.97,0.0]
` is not a valid python. Please use valid code

Comment: @balderman My list1 is a column from a dataframe and I converted it into a list by doing .tolist()

Comment: @balderman The code shown is not a valid list display, but it is how `list1` would be shown (via `__repr__`) once it is defined. I can accept this as shorthand for a suitably defined list. (If you like, you can read `list1 = [float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), 0.0, ...]`.)

Comment: (Keeping in mind there are many more possible NaN values than just `float('nan')`, but for this question the distinction don't matter.)

Comment: @balderman I updated the list you can check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
list1 =[float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan"),0.0,0.0,45.2,0.0,0.0,12.3,32.3,62.6,19.01,0.0,65.1,1.5,0.0,0.0,41.6,0.0,27.4,139.21,0.0,27.75,696.94,66.97,0.0]
list2 = [0.27, 0.29, 0.24, 0.18]
line2 = np.array(list2)

for i in range(0, 6):
    line1 = np.array(list1[i+4:i:-1])
    print(np.dot(line1,line2))
```

Multiplication output:

nan                                                                                                                                                                                                            nan                                                                                                                                                                                                            nan                                                                                                                                                                                                            13.108                                                                                                                                                                                                         10.848                                                                                                                                                                                                         11.457

Comment: @AkileshReddy for i in range(0, len(list1)//4):

Comment: I got one more doubt like I have a list1 as 99 values and I want to do this to all so when I do: for i in range(len(list1)) it gives me an error. I lose 4 values which are one nan and 3 zeros from the output, so when I say 95 instead of len(list1) it doesn't give me this error: ValueError: shapes (3,) and (4,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 4 (dim 0). What do I do in this case?

Comment: So you want to process extra 3 values? I think you have to get the remainder from len(list1)%4 (it will be 99%4 = 3), then use that value (3) to cut 3 last elements from your big array, cut 3 elements from list2 and then do np.dot() for these small arrays. It will be just extra lines of your code, going after the "for" cycle above.

Comment: I have created a question on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382055/valueerror-shapes-3-and-4-not-aligned-3-dim-0-4-dim-0

Answer (score 0):

List implements `.__reversed__()` which gives an iterator, so you can use [reversed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) built-in function:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for i in reversed(lst):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
d
c
b
a
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop backwards over a list, you simply reverse it.

```py
for i in list1[::-1]:
    print(i)
```

Pointed out from JiyuuSensei it is preferred to use `reversed()`.

```py
for i in reversed(list1):
    print(i)
```

The only problem with `nan` is, that everything multiplied with it will also be `nan`.

Comment: Using a list's `reversed()` method is preferred, as it just returns an iterator. Slicing copies your entire list for the loop.