# ValueError: shapes (3,) and (4,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 4 (dim 0)

Tags: python, list

I'm getting an error and 4 of my values are missing. When I say len(list1)-4 then I'm not getting any error but I'm missing 4 values in my output.

```
import numpy as np
list1 = [float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan"),float("nan"),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45394.23,0,0,0,128605.34,321513.36,64302.67,192908.01]
list2 = [0.27, 0.29, 0.24, 0.18]
line2 = np.array(list2)

for i in range(len(list1)):
    line1 = np.array(list1[i+4:i:-1])
    print(np.dot(line1,line2))
```

The output I want is

> ```
> nan
> nan
> nan
> nan
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 12256.442100000002
> 13164.3267
> 10894.6152
> 8170.9614
> 34723.4418
> 124104.1558
> 141465.87689999997
> 171045.1046
> ```

What is the mistake done here?

Comment: Printing `line1` at each turn through the loop should make it obvious what goes wrong. I'm too lazy to figure out by the numbers what you want to happen, so perhaps you could explain that in words? You are getting four-element slices out of list1. What do you want to happen at the end of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues.

- Your index is running through the length of the list, but you're modifying the index (i.e. `i+4`) which pushes your index beyond the range of the list. Python does not error on this as expected, so you're expected to resolve it manually.
- Your indexing misses the first NAN element.

Consider the following modification to your for loop, which will run through the whole loop and tell you what's going on, and your issue should be pretty obvious:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(f"Considering list1[{i+4:2}:{i:2}:-1] = {list1[i+4:i:-1]}")
    line1 = np.array(list1[i+4:i:-1])
    try:    np.dot(line1,line2)
    except: print(f"Error: Tried dotting {line1} with {line2}")

--------
OUTPUT: 

Considering list1[ 4: 0:-1] = [0, nan, nan, nan]
Considering list1[ 5: 1:-1] = [0, 0, nan, nan]
Considering list1[ 6: 2:-1] = [0, 0, 0, nan]
Considering list1[ 7: 3:-1] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
Considering list1[ 8: 4:-1] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
Considering list1[ 9: 5:-1] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
Considering list1[10: 6:-1] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
Considering list1[11: 7:-1] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
Considering list1[12: 8:-1] = [45394.23, 0, 0, 0]
Considering list1[13: 9:-1] = [0, 45394.23, 0, 0]
Considering list1[14:10:-1] = [0, 0, 45394.23, 0]
Considering list1[15:11:-1] = [0, 0, 0, 45394.23]
Considering list1[16:12:-1] = [128605.34, 0, 0, 0]
Considering list1[17:13:-1] = [321513.36, 128605.34, 0, 0]
Considering list1[18:14:-1] = [64302.67, 321513.36, 128605.34, 0]
Considering list1[19:15:-1] = [192908.01, 64302.67, 321513.36, 128605.34]
Considering list1[20:16:-1] = [192908.01, 64302.67, 321513.36]
Error: Tried dotting [192908.01  64302.67 321513.36] with [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18]
Considering list1[21:17:-1] = [192908.01, 64302.67]
Error: Tried dotting [192908.01  64302.67] with [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18]
Considering list1[22:18:-1] = [192908.01]
Error: Tried dotting [192908.01] with [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18]
Considering list1[23:19:-1] = []
Error: Tried dotting [] with [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18]
```

Possible Easy-To-Read Solution:

```
import numpy as np
list1 = np.array([
    float("nan"), float("nan"), float("nan"), float("nan"),
    0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,
    45394.23,0,0,0,
    128605.34, 321513.36, 64302.67, 192908.01
])
list2 = np.array([0.27, 0.29, 0.24, 0.18])

for i in range(len(list1)-3):
    print(f"{list1[i:i+4][::-1]} dot {list2} = ", end = '')
    print(np.dot(list1[i:i+4][::-1], list2))

--------
OUTPUT:

[nan nan nan nan] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = nan
[ 0. nan nan nan] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = nan
[ 0.  0. nan nan] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = nan
[ 0.  0.  0. nan] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = nan
[0. 0. 0. 0.] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 0.0
[0. 0. 0. 0.] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 0.0
[0. 0. 0. 0.] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 0.0
[0. 0. 0. 0.] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 0.0
[0. 0. 0. 0.] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 0.0
[45394.23     0.       0.       0.  ] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 12256.442100000002
[    0.   45394.23     0.       0.  ] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 13164.3267
[    0.       0.   45394.23     0.  ] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 10894.6152
[    0.       0.       0.   45394.23] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 8170.9614
[128605.34      0.        0.        0.  ] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 34723.4418
[321513.36 128605.34      0.        0.  ] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 124104.1558
[ 64302.67 321513.36 128605.34      0.  ] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 141465.87689999997
[192908.01  64302.67 321513.36 128605.34] dot [0.27 0.29 0.24 0.18] = 171045.1046
```